# Optimizing if case in c++ for calling member functions

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization, code-duplication

```
HRESULT Block::SendAlarm(const std::string& variableName, USHORT value)
{
    if (variableName == aAtt_name_Fault)      builder.Alarms().Fault(value);
    if (variableName == aAtt_name_BATT)       builder.Alarms().BATT(value);
    if (variableName == aAtt_name_PWR)        builder.Alarms().PWR(value);
    if (variableName == aAtt_name_OCCLUSION)  builder.Alarms().OCCLUSION(value);
 ... many if statements follows
        
        return S_OK;
}
```

I have the above code, in which builder is a Ventilator object and Alarms() is member class and object of builder. Now am comparing the input strings and calling the member functions of builder.Alarms() using If condition. Is any other better way to do this?

Comment: why do you think this needs to be done in a "better" way? What is "better" ?

Comment: A slight improvement would be to use `else if` to stop comparing after a match is found. And, if one option is extremely more common, you could put that first.

Comment: May be a `std::map` of `variableName` s as enums keys and pointer to the member functions of `Alarms` class as values?

Comment: Besides the "natural" change to use `else if`, have you measured and benchmarked an optimized build to make sure this is one of the top two or three bottlenecks in your program? If it's not, then you probably don't need to refactor this code.

Comment: And if you *always* going to return the same value, unconditionally, then perhaps you don't need to return a value at all?

Comment: @Raffallo For 4 strings i think it's doubtful. One would have to test.

Comment: the member function call will be fast, but if you can change the control type from string to an enum that will help (you'll probably need to accept string in one place, convert to enum, and do numeric comparisons between enums everywhere else)